# How to use forEach in ionic 4?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an app in ionic v1 and I am upgrading into ionic 4. In my app have a forEach loop and I want to write in ionic 4.

ionic 1-->

```
angular.forEach(this.selectedQuestion.answers, function (ans) {
  if (ans.id == answerPassed.id) {
    this.selectedQuestion.selectedAns = answerPassed.id;
  } else {
    ans.value = false;
  }
});
```

and showing this error

> Cannot find name 'angular'.ts(2304)

Answer (score 3):

Like this

```
let num = [7, 8, 9];
num.forEach(function (value) {
  console.log(value);
});
```

or

```
let num = [7, 8, 9];
num.forEach((value) => {
  console.log(value);
});
```

Personally I prefer the 2nd method

Useful links

https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/forEach
or
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_array_foreach.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forEach` on `this.selectedQuestion.answers` instead like below.

```js
this.selectedQuestion.answers.forEach(ans => {
    ans.id == answerPassed.id ? this.selectedQuestion.selectedAns = answerPassed.id : ans.value = false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
this.selectedQuestion.answers.forEach(ans => {
     if (ans.id == answerPassed.id) {
        this.selectedQuestion.selectedAns = answerPassed.id;
      } else {
        ans.value = false;
      }
    })
```